# Jquery and memory

Tags: jquery, performance

I'm considering a possibility of doing some computation by jquery only.
I would need to save few huge hashes in memory.

I wonder how much  memory is allocated for one hash, which contains double value and a date   and has 7k entries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a rough estimate, with chrome heap snapshot (fiddle used: http://jsfiddle.net/Hukps/3/)
First snapshot is without any data, then snapshots increase by 7000 records.

[image]

So I would say something like 0.6-0.7 MB.

fiddle code:

```
window.data = [];
$(go).click(function(){
    var count = 7000;

    for (var i = 0; i< count ; i++)
    {
        window.data.push({
            d:9007199254740992,
            dt: new Date()
        });
    }
    console.log(window.data.length);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You probably don't need jQuery
2. Use [JSPERF](http://jsperf.com) to test which is faster
3. Use your browser's debugging/js tools to profile the memory usage ([Here is how to do it in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/heap-profiling))
4. You probably don't need jQuery

Comment: Do You  mean, that it is better to do it on the server side (see point 1)? Or you mention, that I can use javascript only? Thanks, I will have a look.

Comment: jQuery is (mostly) a DOM manipulation library. You can do your computations in Vanilla JS